# Link breaks in Minecraft Chat?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am building a plugin that requires a user to click on a Long link in chat. Somethig like this:

`http://www.example.com/sample.php?code=124ds8g89fgfg9fd9g76hg89f7d698d67fgh7`

Whenever i send this to the user:

```
sender.sendMessage(url);
```

Only part of the link is copied...example: `http://www.example.com/sample.php?code=124ds8`

How do i make minecraft accept the full URL length? I do not want to use 3rd Part Url shorten-ers either. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use a URL shortener?  This is **the** use case for them.

Comment: Because the link is an API call, and i can not store those. Twitter will not allow you will they? Also, it make the plugin more bulky. Is there some work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minecraft will automatically wrap onto the next line, or cut of a part of the Link/Message if it is too long, it can only fit so many characters into the textbox.

Your best bet is to use something like [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) or [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) to shorten the links into something more manageable.